# How to parse String and get certain value

Tags: java, regex

I should parse a string like this:

```
casale-monferrato/incomincia-oggi-roma-l-ultimo-atto-processo-eternit-davanti-corte-cassazione-74506.html
```

what I want to save the number at the end of the string, the one between `"-" and ".html"` (in this case `74506`).

The parsing must be with the only condition that is considered the last number ONLY NO other number should be considered.

How can I do this in java ?
What is the correctly `regexp` that I must use ?

Comment: `the last number ONLY NO other number`. Better would have been then to put other numbers in the string too.

Comment: There are some good answers below but had you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below regex to match only the last number.

```
"(?<!\\d)\\d+(?=\\D*$)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jA9uH2/1)

```
String s = "casale-monferrato/incomincia-oggi-roma-l-ultimo-atto-processo-eternit-davanti-corte-cassazione-74506.html";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)\\d+(?=\\D*$)");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
 }
```

Output:

```
74506
```

Regular Expression:

```
(?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
  \d                       digits (0-9)
)                        end of look-behind
\d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                           times)
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                           the string
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex to match:

```
\b\d+(?=\D*$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bE3iR3/1)

`(?=\D*$)` will make sure there is no number after matched number hence matching the very last number.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for regexp. Try this instead:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String url =
            "casale-monferrato/incomincia-oggi-roma-l-ultimo-"
                    + "atto-processo-eternit-davanti-corte-cassazione-74506.html";
    final String n = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, url.lastIndexOf('.'));
    System.out.println(n);
}
```